# Insert new line if file contain string

Tags: grep, find, sed, awk, cut

I need to insert 'import packagename' to the line after imports. In files which contains the specific word.
What I try:

```
find iOS/Chat \
  -type f \
  -name "*.swift" \
  -exec gsed -e "/Behavior/ " -e "20a import RxSwift" -i {} +;
```

Also tried:  `-exec gsed -e "/Behavior/20a import RxSwift" -i {} +;`
Looks like not work this construction.

gsed - gnused, I did't find how make to work with bsd sed.
mac os.

**UPD: Closely result**

```
find iOS/Chat -type f -name "*.swift*" -exec grep -iHn "Behavior" {} \; | cut -d: -f-1 | xargs gsed -i '/import Foundation/a import RxSwift'
```

**Cons:**

- if set `gsed -i '/import/a import RxSwift' its called for each import enter line. I want only first. Something like:` gsed -i '0,/import/a import RxSwit'` not work for me...

Still investigating....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

- `brew install gsed` - needed

```
find ./ \                                                                                                                                                          
 -type f \
 -name "*.swift*" \
 -exec grep -lHn "Reachability" {} \; | cut -d: -f-1 | xargs gsed -i -e '/import/{i\import RxReachability' -e ':a;n;ba}'
```

How `sed` first occurrence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970915/887325

- `find` - find all files contain `Reachability` text;
- `cut` - only path
- `xargs` - path files as argument for `gsed`
- `gsed` - find first `import`'s line contains {i\ - insert new line: `import RxReachability`

I hope this answer will be useful for me in 90 years old.